# Update just 'Comments' MembershipUser Property

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to update just the 'Comments' property in ASP. NET MembershipUser and want to leave all other property untouched. Here is my codes

```
MembershipUser userComments = Membership.GetUser(sUserName);
userComments.Comment = "Need Change Password";
Membership.UpdateUser(userComments);
```

It throws an expection 'The E-mail supplied already exists in the database for the application' at Membership.UpdateUser(userComments)

How can I just update only the 'Comments' without changing emails or any other properties?

Comment: What's the exception type you're getting? According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.updateuser?view=netframework-4.8) `UpdateUser()` only throws `ArgumentNullException`. It is `CreateUser()` that throws [MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus?view=netframework-4.8) though error message is not exactly the same.

Comment: Looks like it gives the ProviderException System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it is throwing configuration exception. You can ignore this validation by setting `requiresUniqueEmail` to `false` in your web.config.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
  ....
  requiresUniqueEmail="false"
  ....
/>
```

However it is possible that you have a duplicate email in your database and the framework doesn't know for which one you're trying to update `Comment`. So to get rid of the duplicate might be a better option.

Comment: Yes, that is it. requiresUniqueEmail="false" did the trick. Thanks a lot for your great help.